# Jersey - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: jersey, cors

Error Screenshot :

[image]

The following is my API class in which I have written code for @OPTIONS method.

```
@OPTIONS 
    public Response OptionsFirstRequst(){
         return Response.ok()
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
      .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*").build();
    }
```

I have created a class called Response Builder using which for each request I send response.
The following is the code for the Response Builder class:

```
    public class ResponseBuilder {

    public int status;
    public HashMap data;
    public String error;

    public static Response ok(int Status_code, HashMap<String, String> data, String Response_error) {
        if (data == null) {
            data = new HashMap();
        }

        ResponseBuilder response = new ResponseBuilder();
        response.status = Status_code;
        response.data = data;
        response.error = Response_error;

        return Response.status(Status_code).entity(response)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*").build();
    }

    public static Response error(int Status_code, HashMap<String, String> data, String Response_error) {
        if (data == null) {
            data = new HashMap();
        }

        ResponseBuilder response = new ResponseBuilder();
        response.status = Status_code;
        response.data = data;
        response.error = Response_error;
        response.data = new HashMap();

        return Response.status(Status_code).entity(response)
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
                .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*").build();
    }

}
```

I also have a Request filter which validates token for each request , except for login.

I am able to login , generate token and give it back to the browser.
But after login if I click on profile.

I get response as 200 (as shown in the dev-tools network of the browser) , but I am not getting any data/correct response.

And I am getting the following error.

**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check and add CORS headers, a common solution is to use a [`javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html). Here an example, where the allowed origins are configured in a class `ApplicationConfig.accessControlAllowedOrigins`:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.io.IOException;

@Provider
public class ResponseCorsFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, 
            ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> responseHeaders = responseContext.getHeaders();
        String origin = requestContext.getHeaderString("Origin");
        if (null != origin && 
            (ApplicationConfig.accessControlAllowedOrigins.contains(origin) ||
                 ApplicationConfig.accessControlAllowedOrigins.contains("*"))) {

            responseHeaders.putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            responseHeaders.putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 
                "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD");

            String reqHead = requestContext.getHeaderString(
                "Access-Control-Request-Headers");

            if (null != reqHead && !reqHead.equals("")) {
                responseHeaders.putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", reqHead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `ApplicationConfig.accessControlAllowedOrigins` look like in `ApplicationConfig` ?

Comment: It is a string containing the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Origin. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORSe.g. a Wildcard or a Single url, or a comma separated list of urls.

Comment: The link above by @MeikoRachimow is now broken. My guess is that the new link is now https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: @DanielVerem no it was a link to jersey https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html
i changed it in the answer